# Table and jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Доброго времени суток!
У меня есть таблица с данными которые я беру с базы. Напротив каждой строки есть кнопка Редактировать. Мне нужно с помощью jQuery сделать чтобы по клику на кнопку я мог по отдельности получить все значения тегов <td> того <tr> где currentnumber равен currentnumber кнопки которую нажал.

```
<table rules="ALL">
    {foreach $row as $key => $item}
        <tr currentnumber="{$i++}"/>
            <td>{$i}</td>
            <td>{$item.SURENAME}</td>
            <td>{$item.NAME}</td>
            <td>{$item.ADDRESS}</td>
            <td>{$item.TELEPHONE}</td>
            <td>{$item.ZARPLATA}</td>
            <td>{$item.REG_DATE}</td>
            <td style="border:none"><input type="button" value="Редактировать" name="change" currentnumber="{$i}"/></td>       
        </tr>
    {/foreach}    
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так?

```
$('button').click(function(){
var currentnumber = $(this).attr('currentnumber');
$('tr').each(function(){
if ($(this).attr('currentnumber') == currentnumber) alert('Тут получаете значения td');
});
});
```